# Adding new record by combining two entity objects into single view object in Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I am trying to add new record using ADF form in which I have two EOs combined in single VO like emp_login and emp_details.

But when I am doing + operation emp_details gets its field blank(expected) but emp_login fields becomes disabled.

Also I have tried to create a View based on this 2 tables in database and then created VVO from this view. It keeps enabled all the fields but data is not getting persisted.

So how can I create a signle ADF form which allows me to insert new data in multiple tables at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the VO definition did you indicate that both EOs are updatable?
by default the second one you'll add will be reference only.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply Shay
its really honor for me that you have given response to my question

and sorry for late response 

Exactly you specified I have made both EOs updateble and issue is resolved